# Error logging and retrieval in an ad-hoc application build?

Tags: ios, logging

Hi there friends
Is there someway that we can log errors from a ad-hoc build running on a testers iphone and mail it?

The situation is, the application runs fine, but it depends on a lot of factors, location etc and crashes on the ad-hoc testers phone; the ad-hoc tester is in a totally different country.

Is there anyway to generate an error log when the app crashes and mail it or send it to a server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tester is under your control :) and has an access to Xcode he can mail you the crash log that appears in the Organizer (Ctrl+Cmd+O). I think it’s also possible to retrieve the crash logs without Xcode, [Google for that](http://www.google.com/search?q=retrieve+iphone+crash+logs).

Comment: thanks zoul, i have tried to take a look at iTunes crash logs, looks like greek to me - any way to get "readable" crash logs?

Answer (score 1):

Try Hoptoad notifier (former Crashbucket): http://hoptoadapp.com/pages/ios-notifier

Comment: thanks ricardo, am looking at hoptoadapp, might consider it, but gotta take a good look at it before i jump into it.

Comment: i have signed up for hoptoadapp, but there is no clear documentation on how to add a log for IOS. All they talk about is the writeTestLog